# Angular 2/4 Master Detail Patterns

Tags: angular

I've been working with Angular for a few months now and started to notice a few patterns with master details where the details is some edit form.

**Parent - Child Component Pattern**
If my details component is a child of the master component I can simple use an Input for the selected object and bind properties and hide show the different components, this pattern seems to work great

**Parent - Modal Pattern**
same as above but usually use one component and just loading the row in a modal

**Route Params Pattern** 
If my details is not a child and I use the router, well this only accepts a  string so I pass the id and find myself having to make an api call to get the selected object since the route params only support a string and not passing an object. This seems like a use case when maybe the parent doesn't contain all the properties the detail or the form needs.

**Shared Service Pattern**
Using a Service to Share data between the 2 components

Any thoughts or any other patterns I'm missing?

Comment: Why is it the router's job to pass data to components? It's the router's job to push state into the window's history. It's our job to pass the necessary data in the route's URL to retrieve the object desired.

Comment: not really saying it should be it's job, I'm just noticing patterns and noticed when using route params I'm more than likely making a redundant call to an api if all the object properties match or need some type of share service between the components or need to just use the parent child but if the object properties are different then makes more sense to just use the route params or just make a redundant call, not that it's a big deal.

Comment: I edited the question, it was a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation, you can kinda "cache" your data in Service.

```
@Component({})
export class Component1{
    constructor(service: Service, router: Router){}

    onSomeAction(id){
        this.service.getEntityById(id);
    }

    redirectToDetails(id: number){
         this.router.navigate(["/details", id]);
    }
}

@Component({})
export class Component2() implements OnInit{

    public entity: Entity;

    constructor(service: Service, acivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.getEntityById(this.activatedRoute.getParams().get("id")).subscribe((entity) => {
            this.entity = entity;
        });
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service{

    public knownEntities: Map<number, Entity> = new Map<>();

    constructor(resource: Resource){
    }

    getNewEntityById(id: number): Observable<Entity>{
        return this.resource.getEntityFromBackendById().map((data) => {
            let entity: Entity = data.json();
            this.knownEntities.push(id, entity);
            return entity;
        });
    }

    getEntityById(id: number): Observable<Entity>{
        let knownEntity: Entity = this.knownEntities.get(id);
        if(knownEntity){
             return Observable.of(knownEntity);
        }else{
             return this.getNewEntityById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach - to have own `RouterParameterService` service which serves as global variable

```
@Inject()
export class RouterParameterService(){

    private _routerParam: any;

    public set routerParam(value: any){
        this._routerParam = value;
    }

    public get routerParam(): any{
        if(!this._routerParam){
            throw Error("No Router param set");
        }
        let tmp = this._routerParam;
        this._routerParam = null;
        return tmp;
    }
}

@Component({})
export class Component1(){

    constructor(service: RouterParameterService, router: Router){}

    navigateAction(){
        this.service.routerParam = {id: 1, fName: "A", lName = "Tim"};
        this.router.navigate("/details");
    }
}

@Component({})
export class Component2() implements OnInit{

    public entity: any;

    constructor(service: RouterParameterService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.entity = this.service.routerParam;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah exactly so that the shared service pattern I was talking about. I just noticed all the different patterns so trying to organize when I should use one over the other.